# Make Game Server DDoS-Protected

Tags: debian, firewall, denial-of-service

I'm a real noob in "server discussions".

Im running game servers on Debian 8 but the datacenter doesn't provide physical firewall, So Im looking for a way to make my servers ddos protected, I did blocked all ports except SSH Port, GameServer Ports, FTP Port, MySQL Port and HTTP Port..

I also changed SSH Port so It's harder to attack my server using SSH Port.

Server only returns ping when I ping it on GameServer port, SSH port, HTTP Port and FTP Port, other ports are blocked or only reachable from the localhost.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to hide my server IP and list the server with domain?
2. Is there any way to use CDN on a gameserver?
3. What else can I do to make my server more protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Is there anyway to hide my server IP and list the server with domain?

*No*. A domain name is just a human-friendly alias for an IP address. Try typing in a command prompt:

```
nslookup superuser.com
```

Using a domain name avoids you from giving the exact IP to your users, but does not hide anything. Even if you pick the server from a server selection screen in-game, without seeing its IP or domain name, you can get the IP by analysing packets with a tool like Wireshark.

## Is there anyway to use CDN on a gameserver?

There again, *no*. A CDN is for static content, like HTML pages or JavaScript source files. What you can do is load-balancing, but you will need several game servers, and depending on your game, there is no guarantee that they will work together anyway.

## What else can I do to make my server more protected?

- Choose a server provider that offers DDoS protection. I'm renting a server at [Kimsufi](https://kimsufi.com), they offer free DDoS protection with all of their servers (I don't work for them, I'm just one of their clients).
- If the server software has anti-DDoS protections, make sure they are enabled (I doubt a game server has any, but for instance OpenVPN has some).
- You can host your game server in a VPN you own, but this will only move the problem towards the VPN server (which still can have more anti-DDoS protections).
- Make sure the SSH of your server is hardened. Disable password authentication (at least for `root`) and install an anti-bruteforce program like `fail2ban`. Disable SSH1, and make sure RSA keys (if there are any) are at least 2048 bits long.
- Make sure your server is up to date. Regularly run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` (or the appropriate equivalent for your OS).
- Block the FTP port, unless you have a specific application that ***absolutely*** requires FTP, you can use SFTP for file transfers, which operates over the SSH port.
- Make sure that whatever you do with `iptables`, you also do it with `ip6tables`. Also make sure that after that, you actually *save* the rules:

  iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

  ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6

(might need to be adapted to your distro)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My clients are from Iran, I have to provide them low ping servers, since they have bad ping on every country except Iran, I can't rent a server from Kimsufi or somewhere like that, Renting a server with physical firewall and DDoS Protection is go expensive in Iran, The best thing they can do is set a rule to make server Iran Access everytime it get attacked. Can u gimme a link about OpenVPN Software Firewall ? Your answer where helpful thanks <3

Comment: OpenVPN is not a firewall, it's a Virtual Private Network (VPN) software - basically a soft that will emulate a LAN over the Internet. Bad idea if your users need low-ping server, since it just adds the overhead of encryption and encapsulation. It's not easy to set up, I suggest you google for a tutorial if you're still interested. As for good firewalls I don't think any is better than `iptables` without also affecting performances. Just don't forget to make sure you apply rules to both `iptables` and `ip6tables` and that they are persisted.

Comment: I know, I used word Firewall cause u said  it has some functions to do something like firewall does :D. about `iptables-save` , I didn't use this command but rules I set were working!! Is it Ok If I set connection limit all connected IPs ? is it possible ? and does it helps me ?

Comment: You don't nedd `iptables-save` to *apply* the rules, but you need it to prevent your server form *forgetting* them when it reboots. As for OpenVPN, its anti-DDoS protections only apply to itself, and add to the already heavy overhead of the VPN.

Comment: DDoS protection will not prevent a DDoS attack 100% of the time.  So your server or service can still be the victim of a DDoS attack.  If it happens you deal with it.